# Effectively wrapping public sdk types in golang

Tags: go

I am using pagerduty go [sdk](https://godoc.org/github.com/PagerDuty/go-pagerduty) to do a bunch of api requests.
Particularly I am making use of

`func NewClient(authToken string)  *Client`

to create a new Client type. I want to add some utility functions to my own work to `*Client`. I tried doing this:

```
type BetterPdClient *pagerduty.Client

func NewClient(auth string) BetterPdClient {
    return pagerduty.NewClient(auth)

}

func (b *BetterPdClient) DoSomething() {
    b.GetIncident(....)
}

func main() {
    pd_client := NewClient("")
    fmt.Println(pd_client)
    pd_client.DoSomething()
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
invalid receiver type *BetterPdClient (BetterPdClient is a pointer type)
```

I understand that `DoSomething()` is expecting a pointer as caller. Only other way I could think of is sending the ptr as a function argument:

```
func NewClient(auth string) *pagerduty.Client { 
    return pagerduty.NewClient(auth) 

} 

func DoSomething(cl *pagerduty.Client) { 
    fmt.Println(cl) 
} 

func main() { 
    pd_client := NewClient("") 
    fmt.Println(pd_client) 
    DoSomething(pd_client) 
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: The error message shows up because `*BetterPdClient` would become a `**Client` which is a pointer of a pointer and not valid (and probably not what you want). I would say just change it to `type BetterPdClient pagerduty.Client` (remove the pointer) and change according to that. But you can just make Do something a value method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a type as a *pointer* to another type is almost never what you want because Go doesn't allow you to add methods to that new type, nor to the pointer of that type as you've already figured out yourself. This one doesn't compile either:

```
type T struct{}

type P *T

func (P) M() {}
```

If you want to "extend" a type without "hiding" it's existing functionality your best bet is to embed it in a struct.

```
type T struct{
    // ...
}

func (T) M() {}

type U struct {
    *T
}

func NewU() *U {
    return &U{&T{}}
}

func (U) N() {}

func main() {
    u := NewU()

    u.M()
    u.N()
}
```

And what I mean by "hiding existing functionality" is that when you define a new type in terms of another, already existing type, your new type will not get *direct* access to the methods of the existing type. All you're doing is just saying that your new type should have the same *structure* as the already existing type. Although it's worth pointing out that this property gives you the ability to *convert* one type to the other...

```
type T struct{
    // ...
}

func (T) M() {}

type U T

func NewU() *U {
    return &U{}
}

func (U) N() {}

func main() {
    u := NewU()

    u.M() // compile error
    u.N()

    // convert *U to *T and then call M
    (*T)(u).M()
}
```

Comment: Note that the first section applies *only to pointer types*. You can define, say, `type MyType int` and define methods on `MyType` just fine.